# Pressed state on Buttons inside Gallery for Smartwatch 2

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I'm using the Gallery to get some swipeable items on the swartchwatch 2 (like ViewPager on Android). In each item i have some simple buttons. As the clickHandling for views inside Gallery-Items is part of the framework (implementing onListItemClick() that provides the id of the clicked button instead of setting Listeners on ControlViews) and the normal Android drawable-selectors don't work on SmartWatch2 i' ve found no way to provide a pressed-state for the buttons inside Gallery-Items. I think f.e. the official Gmail-Extension provides pressed-states at least for whole List-Items (but also not for concrete views inside the items).

I've tried ControlExtension.sendImage(refId, drawableId) to update the pressed button, but it doesn't seem to work (i guess because the views in question are not direct ControlViews but part of List/Gallery-items).

So is this even possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible in the current framework.

Comment: That's a pity! But i already expected it, thx to make that clear from official side.